# Magento i can get subtotal value in template files but nowhere else?

Tags: magento-1.9

I am currently working on Magento 1.9.1 and i have really strange problem.

Right now i am using this line of code to call the subtotal value of my shopping cart in any of my template files:

`$subs = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getSubtotal();`

When i do that i get the value in any template .phtml file.

But there is something strange..

When i try to get this value in non template files like php files stored in `/app/code/local/` i can not get the value ?
The whole function:

```
    <?php
        class AG_Fee_Model_Fee extends Varien_Object{

            public static function getFee(){             
            $subtotal = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getSubtotal();
                $feeAmt = Mage::getStoreConfig('checkout/fee/fee_amt');
                return $subtotal;
            }
            public static function canApply($address){
                $setFee = Mage::getStoreConfig('checkout/fee/active');
                if($setFee==1)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
```

Why i can not get it there ?

Comment: i know there is a problem when trying to access session in custom module when using wrong controller class. which controller class are you using? just a clue but try Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action instead of Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action

Comment: I updated the question and i added the whole funcion.
So you can check it. Is there a problem with the function ?
Thanks!